# pandas read in csv column as float and set empty cells to 0

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to read in a CSV as a pandas DataFrame and set spaces (or empty cells) to 0 in one line? Below is an illustration of the problem.

**Input:**

```
$ csvlook data.csv    
|------+---+------|
|  a   | b | c    |
|------+---+------|
|      | a | 0.0  |
|  0   | b | 1.0  |
|  1.5 | c | 2.5  |
|  2.1 | d | 3.0  |
|------+---+------|
```

**What I Want:**

```
python% print(df)
    a   b   c
0   0   a   0.0
1   0   b   1.0
2   1.5 c   2.5
3   2.1 d   3.0
```

**What I've Tried:**

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype={'a': float, 'b': str, 'c': float})
```

Which spits out a ValueError due to the whitespace in the 0th row of column a:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Is there a way of replacing strings with 0s when reading in a CSV with pandas?

**Code to Generate Test Data:**

If you want to try it out, here are the lines I used to generate the test data in the above example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[' ', 0, 1.5, 2.1], 'b':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'c': [0, 1, 2.5, 3]})
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pandas will automatically read the empty values with NaN, so from there just fill them with the fillna method, setting the desired new value(in this case 0).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv').fillna(value = 0)
```

Which yields:

```
     a  b    c
0  0.0  a  0.0
1  0.0  b  1.0
2  1.5  c  2.5
3  2.1  d  3.0
```

Also you can set different values for each column by passing a dict.
Imagine we have the following csv file:

```
     a    b    c
0  NaN    a  0.0
1  0.0    b  1.0
2  1.5  NaN  2.5
3  2.1    d  NaN
```

If we want it to be the same as before we should do:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv').fillna(value = {'a':0,'b':'c','c':3})
```

Yielding again:

```
     a  b    c
0  0.0  a  0.0
1  0.0  b  1.0
2  1.5  c  2.5
3  2.1  d  3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost in one line, and might not work in a real case.

You can set missing values to be mapped to NaN in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', na_values=" ")
```

yielding

```
     a  b    c
0  NaN  a  0.0
1  0.0  b  1.0
2  1.5  c  2.5
3  2.1  d  3.0
```

Then, you can run a [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) to change the NaN's to `.0`.

Hence, the following line does it all:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', na_values=" ").fillna(0)
```

gives

```
     a  b    c
0  0.0  a  0.0
1  0.0  b  1.0
2  1.5  c  2.5
3  2.1  d  3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.replace(r'\s+', 0, regex=True)

     a  b    c
0  0.0  a  0.0
1  0.0  b  1.0
2  1.5  c  2.5
3  2.1  d  3.0
```